# Hungarian Method Algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to implement the Hungarian Method Algorithm but I'm having some trouble assigning zeros when following it through by hand. (**Following step 3 here:** [**link**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm#Matrix_interpretation))

If I have a 5x5 matrix:

[image: Initial Matrix]

I go through each row and assign any unassigned zeros (green) and then cross out neighbouring zeros sharing the same row / column (red).

[image: Assigned Zeros]

Then I mark each row/column as follows:

- Rows containing no assigned zeros (X).
- Each column with a zero in a newly marked row (Y)
- Each row with an assignment that falls inside a newly marked column (Z).

[image: Marked Rows / Columns]

And lastly draw lines through each marked column and **un**marked rows, orange cells indicate values at intersecting marked lines.

[image: Lines Drawn]

But as you can see a zero still remains uncovered by a line, I could just search for zeros that are still uncovered and add an extra line but the given steps don't seem to mention anything about this.

What is it that I'm missing or misunderstanding here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this algorithm is that you look for a row(column) with a single 0. If you find one you box it then cross out the column (row). You cycle through rows and columns ignoring any crossed out 0's. In going from your first to second table I get four boxed 0's (green) at (1, 1), (5, 2), (3, 3) and (4, 4).